# Placing the label of the panel from the top of the plot to the top left when using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

How could i place the label of the panel when using facet_wrap () in ggplot2 packages from the top of the plot to the top left of the plot?.
That is to change the position of the number 4, 5,6 and 8 from the top of the plot to the top left.
[image]

Comment: I would suggest you provide your data set and code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if adding this works:

```
+ theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust=0))
```